# How do I add claims from my custom claims provider to Entra External ID/Azure AD access tokens?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2b, microsoft-entra-external-id

I have added a custom claims provider API (following these articles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/customers/concept-custom-extensions and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/custom-extension-get-started) to add a few claims from an external system to access tokens. The problem is that only these custom claims only gets added to the ID tokens and not the access tokens returned.

I am using a new Entra External Identities for Customers tenant, that I set up a few weeks ago, and I'm fairly new to authentication and authorization, so I'm not sure that my expectation of being able to add custom claims to the access token is feasible. It is however needed for my use case where I have to consider decisions being made a long time ago.

I've tried using both the sample SPA sign-in and device code flow samples, but neither of them have the custom claims in the access token, only in the ID token.

Earlier this year, I'm fairly certain I managed to add custom claims to access tokens using Azure AD B2C API Connectors (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector-token-enrichment). Maybe I will have to use that approach instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a Function app, created an **HTTPs trigger function** and edit the code like below:

[image]

Created a custom extension:

[image]

**Registered Azure AD Application:**

[image]

Configured the ***custom claims in the Enterprise Application***:

[image]

I used **Implicit Grant Flow** to generate tokens:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=ClientID&response_type=id_token+token&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid&state=12345&nonce=12345
```

**The claims displayed in the ID token but when I checked the access token, claims are not displayed:**

[image]

> **How do I add claims from my custom claims provider to Entra External ID/Azure AD access tokens?**

**Note** that: To get the custom claims in the access token, you must generate the access token for your own application. The access token generated for other API such as Microsoft Graph, SharePoint etc. doesn't contain the custom claims. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/optional-claims#configure-directory-extension-optional-claims).

Hence to get the custom claims in the access token, I **Exposed an API** in the Azure AD Application like below:

[image]

***Grant API permissions:***

[image]

Now I generated tokens by passing **scope** as **`api://ClientID/.default openid`**

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=ClientID&response_type=id_token+token&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=api://ClientID/.default openid&state=12345&nonce=12345
```

**Now when I decoded access token and ID token custom claims are displayed successfully:**

*Access Token:*

[image]

*ID Token*:

[image]

Comment: A question - I am trying to do the same in Azure B2C. but it says - This is an Azure AD B2C directory. Access to this Api can only be made for an Azure AD directory (non b2c).

Comment: @BrijeshShah What is the question, precisely?

Comment: Hey - I was a bit confused with the Azure B2C vs Azure AD initially when I started utilizing it. But I understood later. So, Thanks but It is now well cleared. no question.

Comment: @Rukmini Are you aware of any reason substituting an Azure hosted . Net8 isolated azure function would return an improperly formatted body? (Reason 1003003)  Works fine when I use an in-process, in portal, .Net6 azure function.