# Custom Claim Provider Token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id

I am trying to set up a custom claim provider with the following instructions so that I can enrich the tokens for an app with additional information.
Instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/custom-extension-get-started
I would like to set ths up for a multi-tenant app.

I set the app to multi-tenant and went through the instructions 1:1.
The azure function returns the json by default without any processing, so that an error source is excluded.
All other things are according to the instructions.
Now, however, if you log in with an external tenant account, the JWT is generated, but without the custom claims.
When I log in with an account from the origin tenant, I get the error message non-retryable error has occured.
In the application details in entra, the application shows that it has failed due to error message 1003006. (CustomExtensionInvalidResponseContentType) The azure function response with the following json.

```json
{"data":{"@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.onTokenIssuanceStartResponseData","actions":[{"@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.tokenIssuanceStart.provideClaimsForToken","claims":{"DateOfBirth":"01/01/2000","ApiVersion":"1.0.0","CustomRoles":["Writer","Editor"]}}]}}
```

Now I am wondering why the claim provider is apparanetly only called up for the origin tenant, causing a error here, and why a JWT is received when logging in with an external tenant account and apparently the claim provider is not called up, because the claims are missing.

Comment: Check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060652/how-do-i-add-claims-from-my-custom-claims-provider-to-entra-external-id-azure-ad