# Microsoft Entra External ID Custom Claims Provider Error 1003003 CustomExtensionInvalidResponseBody

Tags: microsoft-entra-id, microsoft-entra-external-id

my custom claims provider fails because [`There was a problem parsing the custom extension's response body. Check that the API response body is in an acceptable schema for that custom extension type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/custom-extension-troubleshoot#call-your-rest-api-directly).

I want to add `correlationId` (string) and `newUser` (bool) to the tokens.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/custom-claims-provider-reference#:%7E:text=The%20REST%20API%20response%20format%20which%20Azure%20expects%20is%20in%20the%20following%20format%2C%20where%20the%20claims%20DateOfBirth%20and%20CustomRoles%20are%20returned%20to%20Azure%3A) the expected payload for this is:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.onTokenIssuanceStartResponseData",
        "actions": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.tokenIssuanceStart.provideClaimsForToken",
                "claims": {
                    "DateOfBirth": "01/01/2000",
                    "CustomRoles": [
                        "Writer",
                        "Editor"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have checked the logs and my API returns the following, which for me seems compliant (different claims obviously):

```json
{
    "data": {
        "actions": [
            {
                "claims": {
                    "correlationId": "9733d4a8-3c55-48e4-bc1c-7429560752d4",
                    "newUser": true
                },
                "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.tokenIssuanceStart.provideClaimsForToken"
            }
        ],
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.onTokenIssuanceStartResponseData"
    }
}
```

[image]

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060652/how-do-i-add-claims-from-my-custom-claims-provider-to-entra-external-id-azure-ad) is a step-by-step guidance on how to configure this. The only step where I am deviating is that I don't have implcit flow active on my app registration, which afaik is only relevant for testing purposes with https://jwt.ms. In other parts of my Entra External ID setup, activating these is explicitly discouraged in the docs. In fact without even configuring a Redirect Uri in the appr egistration for my custom claims provider API, this is not even visible.

Does someone know why it keeps failing? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well sh... Working now. Apparently, the custom claims provider does not like any property types other than `string`. I removed the `newUser` claim which was a `bool` and now it works.